# Count nodes in a binary tree without leaf?/node? in scheme?

Tags: tree, scheme

I'm attempting to create a function that returns the number of nodes in a given binary tree, but I do not have access to the node? and leaf? functions in the R5RS language. In addition, I don't quite understand the terminating conditions for such a function, since most variants I attempt result in errors from running out of memory. Thanks for any help in advance.

```
(define (make-tree value left right)
  (list value left right))

(define (value tree)
  (car tree))

(define (left tree)
  (cadr tree))

(define (right tree)
  (caddr tree))    

(define (tree-node-count t)
  (cond ((null? t)0)
        ((...?)
        (else (+
               (tree-node-count left)
               (tree-node-count right)))))
```

Comment: There are no `node?` or `leaf?` *procedures* in R5RS Scheme. Just like `value` and `left` they need to be created based on how you model your node.

Comment: The question I was asking is how do I create this function without them? I'm not quite sure how to define them. My best attempt is (define (leaf? n)
  (and (equal? left '())(equal? right '()))) which returned #f when I gave it a leaf.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fact, you don't *need* a `leaf?` or `node?` procedure, if we're counting the number of nodes, simply add `1` for each one of them:

```
(define (tree-node-count t)
  (cond ((null? t) 0)
        (else (+ 1
                 (tree-node-count (left  t))
                 (tree-node-count (right t))))))
```

Comment: When I gave this function the list '(5 1 10) it ran out of memory. Is that the fault of my definitions of (left) and (right) ?

Comment: @TPerson my mistake, the parameters in the recursion had the wrong name. Please try again, and be aware that `'(5 1 10)` is _not_ a correct tree, use this instead: `(tree-node-count '(5 () ()))`

Comment: Thanks it took me a bit of work to understand it, but I finally do.

Answer (score 0):

There are no standard ways of doing binary trees in Scheme so the procedures, like `left` and `right`, `leaf?`, and `node?` have different implementation on different ways of modelling the data. Eg. Here's one using vector:

```scm
(define TYPE-TREE (vector 'TREE)) ; private

(define (make-tree value left right)
  (vector TYPE-TREE value left right))

(define (tree? tree)
  (and (vector? tree)
       (eq? (vector-ref tree 0) TYPE-TREE)))

(define (tree-value tree)
  (vector-ref tree 1))

(define (tree-left tree)
  (vector-ref tree 2))

(define (tree-right tree)
  (vector-ref tree 3))

(define (tree-node-count tree)
  (let aux ((tree tree) (count 0))
    (if (not (tree? tree))
        count
        (aux (tree-right tree)
             (aux (tree-left tree) (+ 1 count))))))

(define test (make-tree 5 (make-tree 2 '() '()) (make-tree 10 '() '())))
(tree-node-count test) ; ==> 3
```

Of course you would wrap this in a library and keep TYPE-TREE hidden. To answer your question you need to replace the procedures with its implementation. In the case of the above model `tree-node-count` would look like this:

```scm
(define (tree-node-count tree)
  (let aux ((tree tree) (count 0))
    (if (not (and (vector? tree)
                  (eq? (vector-ref tree 0) TYPE-TREE)))
        count
        (aux (vector-ref tree 3)
             (aux (vector-ref tree 2) (+ 1 count))))))
```

As you can see it's a simple substitution of the body of the original procedure. I would advice against it of course as this only makes the code and the programmers intention less clear. Removing abstraction won't win you points.